# Loosely tying Terraform version in dokcer-compose.yml file

Tags: docker-compose, terraform, hashicorp

Hi I want to loosely tie terrform version in following block. It's locked to 13.5 I want to do something like >=13.5.

```
version: '3'

services:
  terraform:
    image: hashicorp/terraform:0.13.5
    volumes:
      - ../../:/app
    working_dir: "/app"
    entrypoint: ""
```

Comment: If you specify the tag at the minor version i.e. `hashicorp/terraform:0.13`, then it will be the latest version of 0.13 available from the registry. This is essentailly equivalent to what you are asking, but not exactly.

Answer (score 0):

`image` in the `docker-compose.yml` references a specific image, you can't specify a "greater or equal" version number in this case, see the [Compose file version 3 reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#image).

If this is a hard requirement then I'd suggest creating a custom Docker container and manually installing Terraform. But as Terraform is distributed as a single binary and not via a package manager you'll have to provide logic for the "greater or equal" version number yourself.

Also be careful when operating on the same state file with different Terraform versions.